# Dynamic AJAX promise chain with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, chaining

My AJAX calls are built inside of a for loop. They need to be in order (synchronous). How do I chain them with jQuery?

```
var array = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
var arrayLength = array.length;
for (var arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter < arrayLength; arrayCounter++) {
    var id = array[arrayCounter];
    getData(id);

    function getData(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/' + id,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(d) {
                var response = d;
                console.log(d);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution using `for`:

```
var array = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
var id = array[0];
var data = getData(id);
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Or only the last "i" will be used
    (function (i) {
        data = data.then(function() {
            return getData(array[i]);
        });
    }(i));
}

// Also, see how better the getData can be.
function getData(id) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/' + id,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
    }).done(function(d) {
        var response = d;
        console.log(d);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('ERROR');
    });
}
```

By the way, if you used a proper promises library, such as [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird), you'd use the following code:

```
var array = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
Promise.reduce(array, function(data, id) {
    return data.promise.then(function(result) {
        return { promise: getData(id), results: data.results.push(result) };
    });
}, []).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.results); // yay!
});

function getData(id) {
    return Promise.cast($.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/' + id,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
    }).done(function(d) {
        var response = d;
        console.log(d);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('ERROR');
    }));
}
```

As you can see, way easier to read/write.

Answer (score 12):

Most promise libraries have this built in, with jQuery? Not so lucky:

First, your function should return a promise:

```
 function getData(id) {
        return $.ajax({ // note the return
            url: 'http://example.com/'+id,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (d) {
                console.log(d);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ERROR")
            }
        });
}
```

Now, you chain them in a loop using `.then` calls. Note, that `.then` will execute only after the previous promise has fulfilled. So they will all run in order, one after the other.

```
var array = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
var p = $.when(1); // empty promise
array.forEach(function(el){
    p = p.then(function(){
        return getData(el);;
    });
});
```

All functions will run one after the other. What's left? The return value. The current implementation discards the return value. We can put the return values in an array for example:

```
var array = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
var p = $.when(1); // empty promise
var results = [];
array.forEach(function(el,index){
    p = p.then(function(){
        return getData(el);
    }).then(function(data){
        results[index] = data; // save the data
    });
});
p.then(function(){
    // all promises done, results contains the return values
});
```

Why stop there though, let's make it nicer :) Your entire code can be shortened to

```
["One","Two","Three"].map(makeUrl).map($.get).reduce(function(prev,cur,idx){
    return prev.then(cur).then(function(data){ results[idx] = data; });
},$.when(1)).then(function(){
   // results contains all responses here, all requests are sync
});

function makeUrl(id){
    return "http://example.com"+id+"?callback=?";
}
```

Comment: Did you really use the word "shortened"?

Comment: Yes, I believe I did.