# While or For loop with an AJAX query

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to control an ajax query with a while or for loop. My intention is to have the loop execute 4 times and fill in 4 values with the same query. The problem I have is that, of course, the AJAX request is async and can take time. So I either end up with a frozen browser or a loop that completes before it can assign the values.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 4) {
    doAjaxReq().done(function (result) {
        if (i == 0) val1 = result;
        else if (i == 1) val2 = result;
        else if (i == 2) val3 = result;
        else if (i == 3) val4 = result;
    });
}
```

if I place i++ outside of the ajax request, it will of course complete the loop before all the requests are done. If I place the i++ inside the ajax.done() I will crash the browser.

What can I do?

Comment: Why dont use array to put result ?

Comment: I don't know what the difference would be.. I still need 4 ajax calls.

Comment: can you try recursion?

Comment: You never increment `i` - this runs forever?

Comment: Theres a better way to skin the cat. You can pass a context to the ajax call (giving `this` within the callback meaning (e.g. `this=val1`, or `this=val2`)). Also, probably want to look into the [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic AJAX promise chain with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736281/dynamic-ajax-promise-chain-with-jquery)

Comment: You probably should consider reviewing your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
   function request(i){
      if(i> 3) return;

    doAjaxReq().done(function (result) {
            if (i == 0) val1 = result;
            else if (i == 1) val2 = result;
            else if (i == 2) val3 = result;
            else if (i == 3) val4 = result;

              request(i+1);
        });
    }

//somewhere
request(0);
```

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this and it works. I simply used recursion and if I hit it 4 times I returned

Answer (score 2):

The `.done()` handler will get called some time LATER.  That means your `for` or `while` loop will be entirely done and `i` will be at it's terminal value.  So, you either have to find a different structure or you have to put `i` into a closure so it's value is preserved. Which to do  depends upon whether you really want to run the ajax calls in parallel or in sequence.

If parallel is OK (all ajax calls in flight at the same time), then you have these options:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // create closure to capture the value of `i`
    (function(index) {
        doAjaxReq().done(function (result) {
            if (index == 0) val1 = result;
            else if (index == 1) val2 = result;
            else if (index == 2) val3 = result;
            else if (index == 3) val4 = result;
        });
     })(i);
}
```

Or, it's probably makes the coding easier to put the results into an array and use promise functions to know when everything is done:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4;i++) {
    promises.push(doAjaxReq());
}
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(r1, r2, r3, r4) {
    // all ajax calls are done here and 
    // results are in r1[0], r2[0], r3[0], r4[0]
});
```

---

If you are trying to sequence the ajax calls one after another (wait for one to finish before launching the next one), then you can use this structure:

```
 var cntr = 0;
 var results = [];
 function next() {
     doAjaxDone().done(function(data) {
         ++cntr;
         results.push(data);
         if (cntr < 4) {
             next();
         } else {
             // all ajax calls done here and results are in results array
         }
     })
 }
```

Comment: @dave - you're right - I have corrected.  Such an oversight that it doesn't support arrays directly since this is the most common usage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the finest solution, but I can't think about something simpler

```
var i = 0;
var results = [];

function xx(){

    if(i >= 4){
        return;
    } else {

        doAjaxReq().done(function (result) {        
            //avoid if and elseif
            results[i] = result;

            i++;
            xx();
        });

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Never increments `i` and runs all calls at once, thus mixing all the values of `i`.

Comment: Now, it puts all the results into `results[3]`.  Also isn't calling `xx()` to start things.

Comment: @jfriend00 forgot to add the incrementation, not the initial call to the function, I was providing only the recursive function. I don't comprehend the part of _mixing values_ , I thought that op was attempting to store every response in a separate variable. this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lbrd9q9/) is working and putting all values in separate indexes of the array.

Comment: That's because your jsFiddle is not asynchronous which is the challenge here.  The `.done()` handler is going to get called sometime LATER after all your `xx()` function calls have ALL been called.  That means `i` will be sitting at the value of 3 when all your `.done()` handlers are called.  This is the whole issue with async responses.  If you moved your `i++` and `xx()` inside the `.done()` handler, then it would probably work.

Comment: Oh ok, that's the issue. I'm gonna change that. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your results in a n array like

```
var i = 0;
var ajaxRes=[];
while (i < 4) {
    doAjaxReq().done(function (result) {
       ajaxRes.push(result);
    });
    i++
}
```