# Promises and concurrency

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am going to ask this question again, because I did not have the right problem in mind the last time.

Suppose I have a collection of jQuery selectors in an array:

```
[{menu:'.menu-a',click:'.menu-a-click'},...]
```

I want to iterate through these selectors, and if `menu` does not exist, then if `click` exists, then click...

This is where the trouble starts. I need to click once, then do a timeout before clicking again - which allows the menu to be built by another script, and the second click will hide it.

I want to use Promises to regulate all this clicking. It would be like setting up a chain of firecrackers, then lighting the first one... but Promises execute right away. How do I do this?

I can code it in plain old JS, but I want to learn other methods. Something involving `all` or `map`, I suppose.

Comment: iterating object properties , does not guarantee order ( in fact - there is no order) - so you have other problem now. one more thing. supply a demo. your second paragraph is not clear

Comment: The given object is just an example of objects in an array I will iterate. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: How long is the timeout? Is the menu guaranteed to be built after a certain timeout? It would be much better if you had some kind of event that you could listen to that would indicate to you when the menu is ready for another click.

Comment: The checking of the menu is extraneous to the basic question -- I have been getting by with the 100 ms -- because the actual USE of the menu dom doesn't happen until much later. I just need it to be present, and the first click ensures that, and the second click appears to be getting cached for after the build.

Comment: look at the second answer to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736281/dynamic-ajax-promise-chain-with-jquery

Comment: After reading the question through a couple of times, the only reason I can see for using promises would be if the menu-builder script was a server-side. If it's not, then everything should be synchronous - *promises* should be unnecessary, and you would only need *timeouts* to give some visual effect. Straightforwardly you appear to need neither.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 You are right, I don't `need` Promises for this, but then again, who really needs loops either? =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with. Beats a three-legged donkey.

```
var menus=[{id:0},{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];

function doer(menu){
    return new Promise(function called(res,rej){
      console.log('click1:'+menu.id);
      setTimeout(function(){
        if(menu.id===2){return rej(new Error('could not'));}
        console.log('click2:'+menu.id);
        res(1);// happy
      },Math.random()*8000);
    });  
}

Promise.reduce(menus,function(ctr,cur,i){
  return doer(menus[i]).then(function(res,rej){
     console.log('happy:',res);
  });
},$.when(1)).then(function(){
  console.log('everyones done'); //no errors
}).catch(function(eee){
  console.log('Error:',eee);
}).finally(function(){
  console.log('finally');
});
```

This is Bluebird if that matters. I don't know the Bluebird equivalent of `$.when(1)`.

Comment: Btw, if you're using Bluebird, you should go with `Promise.delay` instead of doing your own `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here:

[image]

*Image source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)*

You can use the `onFulfillment` callback to do your neccessary work after the promise is fulfilled.