# Delay subsequent clicks either 2 seconds or after webpage AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox-addon

For a Firefox WebExtension, I need to have several radio buttons that are in a web page clicked.
Therefore, the following code is invoked via `browser.tabs.executeScript()`:

```js
var items = "input[id^='M37_Q_'][id$='_B1']";
var first_item = items + ":first";
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(first_item).offset().top
}, 1000);
$(items).click();
```

However, the original radio buttons are connected to an AJAX call (saving the actual state, that is) and with the code above only 2 out of 10 buttons get clicked.

The underlying `HTML` code is as follows (literally, dozens of them)

```
<div class="radio">
    <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1">
        <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT#B1">
        0
    </label>    
</div>
```

Plus, I don't have (write) access to the source code, nor to the server side which is indeed part of the problem.

Now my question is: How can I somewhat delay the "next" click, so that it is only clicked when the first AJAX call finished successfully (or some time has elapsed, say 2 seconds)?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: At a minimum, this question should include some HTML against which to run the code. Assuming that this already works as written to at least click the buttons, and the only issue is waiting between doing so, then this appears to be completely separate from the fat that it is a WebExtension. As such, you should seriously consider using a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to demonstrate the problem. However, given that you have not provided any of the code to inject your content script, we can not be sure of that.

Comment: @Makyen: Don't you think that links to *How to Ask* and *What topics can I ask about here?* seem somewhat superfluous with 12k rep? But you're right with the server side code.

Comment: Yes, they are a bit. The text is one of my standard auto-comments, intended to provide direction to, mostly new, users so they can edit their questions to be on-topic. However, the fact that you asked this question and then posted a bounty on it indicates that you feel the question is both important to you and in a state that is answerable. However, it really isn't in the state that is reasonably answerable. As it is, anyone that wants to answer it would have to make up HTML code against which to test. Such code would not be as good as having actual code form you against which to run.

Comment: This might help you a bit with chained jQuery AJAX calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736281/dynamic-ajax-promise-chain-with-jquery/22736654#22736654

Comment: In addition, your question asks for two different issues: delay until an AJAX call in the original page completes and just a time delay. These are two *very* different things. Implementing the time delay is relatively easy. Delaying for a specific AJAX call to complete is significantly more complex. In fact, it is impossible without further information. We could delay until after *some* AJAX call completed, but without enough information in the question to be able to identify the AJAX call, there is no way for us to *know* that we are waiting for the completion of the correct AJAX call.

Comment: @Makyen: Once again, you're right. I had [Waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) as used in `selenium` in mind with the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Adding a 2 second delay between clicks

Just adding a 2 second delay between each `click()` is reasonably easy.  You can do so with a [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) loop.

### jQuery

Implementing a 2 second delay between clicks, using jQuery, could be something like:

```js
var items = "input[id^='M37_Q_'][id$='_B1']";

function clickOnceEvery2s($list) {
    if($list.length > 0) {
        //Click the first jQuery object in the list
        $list[0].click();
        //Remove the first jQuery object in the list
        $list.splice(0,1); //jQuery Objects are not actually arrays, but do have .splice().
        if($list.length > 0) {
            //If there are more, do the next one after a 2 second delay. Also check here
            //  for length > 0 so there's not a timeout hanging around which will do
            //  nothing.
            setTimeout(clickOnceEvery2s,2000,$list);
        }
    }
}
clickOnceEvery2s($(items));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT#B1">
    T0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT#B2" checked>
    T1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU#B1">
    U0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU#B2" checked>
    U1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV#B1">
    V0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV#B2" checked>
    V1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW#B1">
    W0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW#B2" checked>
    W1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX#B1">
    X0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX#B2" checked>
    X1
  </label>
    <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY#B1">
    Y0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY#B2" checked>
    Y1
  </label>
  <br/>
</div>
```

### Vanilla JavaScript

If jQuery is not really required, it is also easy to implement the same thing in vanilla JavaScript.

```js
var items = "input[id^='M37_Q_'][id$='_B1']";

function clickOnceEvery2s(array) {
    if(array.length > 0) {
        //Click the first element in the Array
        array[0].click();        
        //Remove the element from the Array
        array.shift();
        if(array.length > 0) {
            //If there are more, do the next one after a 2 second delay. Also check here
            //  for length > 0 so there's not a timeout hanging around which will do
            //  nothing.
            setTimeout(clickOnceEvery2s,2000,array);
        }
    }
}
//Pass the elements in an Array. Uses the spread operator to convert NodeList to Array.
clickOnceEvery2s([...document.querySelectorAll(items)]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT#B1">
    T0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT#B2" checked>
    T1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU#B1">
    U0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU#B2" checked>
    U1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV#B1">
    V0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV#B2" checked>
    V1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW#B1">
    W0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW#B2" checked>
    W1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX#B1">
    X0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX#B2" checked>
    X1
  </label>
    <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY#B1">
    Y0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY#B2" checked>
    Y1
  </label>
  <br/>
</div>
```

## Executing after the AJAX call returns

The way to do this is to override the method which is used to make the AJAX call. If the call is done through jQuery's [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method, then you can override that. However, normally, you would override [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). You would save a copy of the real method and insert one which functions, from the page's point of view, identically as the stock method. However, your code would be called with the response, which allows you to know when the request was complete. This is significantly more complex. In addition, there is not enough information in the question for us to be able to uniquely identify the AJAX call. Thus, the best we would be able to do is to look for an AJAX call that is initiated after the `.click()` and then wait for that AJAX call to complete. While that might be highly likely to be the correct AJAX call, there is no way for us to be sure that it would be the correct AJAX call without more information.

## Potential optimization

Depending on what triggers the page code making the AJAX calls, and if the code which performs the AJAX call reads in the state of all the radio buttons (i.e. not just the one that was clicked), you may be able to change the state of all the radio buttons at once.  What might work is setting the [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-checked) attribute on all the desired radio buttons. Then, you can fire off a single `click` event to trigger the AJAX call.  If this works, then you do not need to wait for the AJAX call to return in order to change subsequent radio buttons. You change all the buttons at once, and the page only makes one AJAX call to change the recorded state of all the buttons. Without the actual code for the page which you are changing, we have no way to know if this will work, but you could try something like:

```js
var items = "input[id^='M37_Q_'][id$='_B1']";
$(items).attr('checked','true')[0].click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT#B1">
    T0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT#B2" checked>
    T1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU#B1">
    U0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETU#B2" checked>
    U1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV#B1">
    V0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETV#B2" checked>
    V1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW#B1">
    W0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETW#B2" checked>
    W1
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX#B1">
    X0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETX#B2" checked>
    X1
  </label>
    <br/>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B1">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY#B1">
    Y0
  </label>
  <label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B2">
    <input type="radio" id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_B2" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY" value="B2" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY_error_1" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETY#B2" checked>
    Y1
  </label>
  <br/>
</div>
<script>
    $('input').click(function(event) {
        console.log('A radio button was clicked.');
    });
</script>
```